# Error importing oracle dump

Tags: oracle, import, dump

I am trying to import a dump into two schema in the same oracle DB.Following a workaround to do this.

I am trying to run the imp command with the INDEXFILE option to be able to modify the tablespace names in the sql. This is what I get :

> E:\oracle_10_2\BIN>imp atlantis/atlantis@orcl file=ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp indexfile=index.sql  full=y log=imp.log
>
> Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Mar 12 15:31:44 2009
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Produc
>   tion
>   With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options
>
> IMP-00002: failed to open ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp for read
>   Import file: EXPDAT.DMP >

Looked like a file permission issue to me so I tried changing it.

> E:\oracle_10_2\BIN>cacls E:\ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp /p atlantis:F
>
> Are you sure (Y/N)?y
>
> processed file: E:\ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp
>
> E:\oracle_10_2\BIN>cacls E:\ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp
>
> E:\ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp CORP\atlantis:F

But the problem persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 10g consider using new export/import tool [Oracle Data Pump](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm#i1009203) in which you can use [REMAP_TABLESPACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref342) parameter.

Anyway, you missed the path of the exportfile (bassed on the commands fo give permissions). Then  You wrote:

```
file=ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp
```

instead of

```
file=E:\ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp
```

Then, the result export command to work is:

```
imp atlantis/atlantis@orcl file=E:\ABCD1_EXCLUDE_CLOB_TABS_BAK.dmp indexfile=index.sql full=y log=imp.log
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of the indexfile option for impdb command?

Comment: You can use REMAP_TABLESPACE to import in diferent tablespaces. I've updated the answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

Open window command line as administrator 
imp user/pass@databasename(listenername) file='DMP path' 
 log=indexfile.log full=y;

Don't forget to add your database or listener name.